# Creating a list of pairs using comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to create a list of pairs, `p`, from 2 ranges,

```
r1 = [i for i in range(0, 10, 2)]
r2 = [j for j in range(10, 0,-2)]
```

Such that,

```
p[0] = [r1[0], r2[1]]
p[1] = [r1[1], r2[1]]
.....
p[-1] = [r1[-1], r2[-1]]
```

Naively I thought,

```
p = [[i, j] for i in range(0, 10, 2) for j in range(10, 0, -2)]
```

would do this but I soon saw the error of my ways.

I also tried,

```
p = [r1[:], r2[:]]
```

but yeah that didn't work either.

Then I tried,

```
p = []
for i, j  in zip(r1, r2):
    p.append([i, j])
```

Which does work!

But that got me wondering, is there a Pythonic way of doing this using list comprehensions?

The 2 ranges will always be the same length in implementation but not always spanning the same domain.

EDIT: to be clear I was wondering if it was possible to generate the ranges `r1` & `r2` within the comprehension as well as the comprehension giving the pairing.

Comment: just `[list(c) for c in zip(r1,r2)]`

Comment: to be clear I want to generate the ranges r1 & r2 within the comprehension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to `list comprehension` for the one that works as mentioned in  code you posted above, may be you can try:

```
[[i,j] for i, j  in zip(r1, r2)]
```

Or to add `range` in `list comprehension`:

```
[[i,j] for i, j  in zip(range(0, 10, 2), range(10, 0, -2))]
```

Comment: see edit to question

Comment: How about `[[i,j]for i, j  in zip(range(0, 10, 2), range(10, 0, -2))]`?

Comment: edit yer answer & the points are yours, thx

Comment: Great that it worked! `Happy Coding`.

Comment: your answer hasn't zipped the ranges

Comment: my mistake! edited